# Vaadin: дублируются значения для Grid

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

Я описал Grid, как описано в [инструкции](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html).

```
@Route
@SpringComponent
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final UserService userService;
    private Label label;
    private Grid<UserDto> grid;

    public MainView(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        initComponents(userService);
    }

    private void initComponents(UserService userService) {
        initHeader();
        initMainGrid(userService);
    }

    private void initMainGrid(UserService userService) {
        grid = new Grid<>(UserDto.class);

        grid.setItems(userService.getAll());

        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getId).setHeader("ID");
        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getUsername).setHeader("Имя пользователя");
        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getPassword).setHeader("Пароль");
        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getEmail).setHeader("email");
        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getPhone).setHeader("Телефон");
        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getActive).setHeader("Активен");

        add(grid);
    }

    private void initHeader() {
        label = new Label("Список пользователей");
        add(label);
    }
}
```

Но данные почему-то дублируются:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, почему дублируются данные? Как избавиться от этого?

Comment: Они же не дублируются. Названия столбцов слева на английском, и они в другом порядке. Попытайтесь не добавлять столбцы, посмотрите, что будет. Я подозреваю, что в конструктор передается уже заполненный UserService. На английском. А вы потом уже добавляете на русском.

Comment: Да, если не добавлять столбцы, то отображается только один список, но я не могу его отсортировать и задать имена. Как это сделать, в таком случае?

Comment: может так `grid.getColumnByKey("password").setHeader("Пароль");` ?

Comment: Да, имена колонок так меняются, но не порядок их отображения.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Теперь класс выглядит так:

```
@Route
@SpringComponent
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final UserService userService;
    private Label label;
    private Grid<UserDto> grid;

    public MainView(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        initComponents(userService);
    }

    private void initComponents(UserService userService) {
        initHeader();
        initMainGrid(userService);
    }

    private void initMainGrid(UserService userService) {
        grid = new Grid<>(UserDto.class);

        grid.setItems(userService.getAll());

        Grid.Column<UserDto> id = grid.getColumnByKey("id");
        Grid.Column<UserDto> username = grid.getColumnByKey("username");
        Grid.Column<UserDto> password = grid.getColumnByKey("password");
        Grid.Column<UserDto> email = grid.getColumnByKey("email");
        Grid.Column<UserDto> phone = grid.getColumnByKey("phone");
        Grid.Column<UserDto> active = grid.getColumnByKey("active");

        id.setHeader("ID");
        username.setHeader("Имя пользователя");
        password.setHeader("Пароль");
        email.setHeader("email");
        phone.setHeader("Телефон");
        active.setHeader("Активен");

        List<Grid.Column<UserDto>> columns = Lists.newArrayList(id, username, password, email, phone, active);
        grid.setColumnOrder(columns);

        add(grid);
    }

    private void initHeader() {
        label = new Label("Список пользователей");
        add(label);
    }
}
```

Не очень лаконично, но вроде Vaadin не славится лаконичностью.